# Set property namespace in openwhisk wsk cli

Tags: openwhisk

I'm trying to create namespace in openwhisk along with auth and api host, but it's not working for me. The official documentation says to use this command. While `-i` is used to bypass the certificates.

```
wsk property -i set \
  --apihost 'http://localhost:3233' \
  --auth '23bc46b1-71f6-4ed5-8c54-816aa4f8c502:123zO3xZCLrMN6v2BKK1dXYFpXlPkccOFqm12CdAsMgRU4VrNZ9lyGVCGuMDGIwP' \
--namespace 'guest'
```

It gives the error `unknown flag: --namespace`
Next, I use it like this, but its still not setting the namespace.

```
wsk property -i set \
  --apihost 'http://localhost:3233' \
  --auth '23bc46b1-71f6-4ed5-8c54-816aa4f8c502:123zO3xZCLrMN6v2BKK1dXYFpXlPkccOFqm12CdAsMgRU4VrNZ9lyGVCGuMDGIwP' \
namespace guest
```

It throws this error. `error: Unable to obtain API build information: The connection failed, or timed out. (HTTP status code 404)`
How to fix this?